# How to send a string to server using s_client

Tags: linux, openssl

How to use `s_client` of `openssl` to send a short `string` to the server?

I have read the [s_client manual](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html#) but didn't find any usable flags.

Or is there any other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to use s_client of openssl to send a short string to the server?

You can `echo` it in. Below, I used a `GET` with`HTTP/1.0` and tweeter rudely refused my request:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 0
```

The `-ign_eof` keeps the connection open to read the response.

Tweeter uses Verisign as the CA. You can fetch *VeriSign Class 3 Primary CA - G5* from [here](http://www.symantec.com/page.jsp?id=roots), and then use it as an argument with `-CAfile` to ensure the chain verifies.

Here are the OpenSSL docs on [`s_client(1)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html).

---

```
$ echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n" | openssl s_client -connect twitter.com:443 -CAfile PCA-3G5.pem -ign_eof
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = "(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN = VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06, CN = VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL CA
verify return:1
depth=0 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3 = US, 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2 = Delaware, businessCategory = Private Organization, serialNumber = 4337446, C = US, postalCode = 94103-1307, ST = California, L = San Francisco, street = 1355 Market St, O = "Twitter, Inc.", OU = Twitter Security, CN = twitter.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware/businessCategory=Private Organization/serialNumber=4337446/C=US/postalCode=94103-1307/ST=California/L=San Francisco/street=1355 Market St/O=Twitter, Inc./OU=Twitter Security/CN=twitter.com
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL CA
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware/businessCategory=Private Organization/serialNumber=4337446/C=US/postalCode=94103-1307/ST=California/L=San Francisco/street=1355 Market St/O=Twitter, Inc./OU=Twitter Security/CN=twitter.com
issuer=/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3724 bytes and written 446 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 53BE6F30E6C52AAFFC01EAD8D5938C78...
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 87810BE6303E8EB831EC63E243D4C6E7...
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 129600 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 95 93 d8 f3 27 2f 4c 11-ab 14 ee 04 46 e3 a8 e5   ....'/L.....F...
    0010 - 7f 35 16 07 6d 5e 80 7c-fa 1d cd 78 39 7e 82 0b   .5..m^.|...x9~..
    0020 - 1d ee d6 99 2d d2 03 db-ab b8 37 5d f5 a5 28 62   ....-.....7]..(b
    0030 - 3b f6 c7 c3 dc 7c 77 de-0f 60 d8 4c 8c f6 8e 8b   ;....|w..`.L....
    0040 - c8 8e 65 68 96 ec 27 f1-26 5d 4c 25 49 fd c0 ca   ..eh..'.&]L%I...
    0050 - c5 86 00 19 f1 26 5a 3e-fd df ca 12 a9 f8 17 bb   .....&Z>........
    0060 - 77 b8 5b 1c 58 1a 6b 16-d1 16 e0 d9 e8 b2 bf 92   w.[.X.k.........
    0070 - 44 07 60 17 a0 11 23 52-3a 14 d0 79 85 a3 ae 8d   D.`...#R:..y....
    0080 - 17 d1 b8 44 d7 c3 3e ab-67 4c 7a c0 d6 cd 7e fe   ...D..>.gLz...~.
    0090 - b7 95 56 69 8f 5f 3e ee-2a c1 f9 0e 46 75 a6 79   ..Vi._>.*...Fu.y

    Start Time: 1398724229
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 0

closed
```

Comment: Note that if you can use `echo -n blah` to send a string without trailing newline,

Answer (score 6):

```
echo "YOUR TEXT HERE" | openssl s_client -connect host:port
```

Comment: `echo "YOUR TEXT HERE" | openssl s_client -connect host:port-ign_eof` to send string and get the response from the server

Answer (score 1):

The `openssl s_client` application can be used to send data to the web server with some creative bash scripting.

```
  connectToHost="localhost:8443" ; \
  dataToPost='{login: "Hello-world", password:"secret"}'; \
  dataLen=$(expr length "${dataToPost}" ) ; \
  ( printf "POST / HTTP/1.1\n" ; \
    printf "Host: %s\n" "${connectToHost}"; \
    printf "Content-Length: %d\n" "$((dataLen+1))" ; \
    printf "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n" ; \
    printf "%s\n" "${dataToPost}" ; \
    sleep 1.5 ) | openssl s_client -connect ${connectToHost}
```

The printf and sleep statements are grouped together with parentheses to keep the pipe open until s_client has had a chance to send the request and receive a response. This delays the end-of-file signal so the `-ign_eof` option is not needed. The disadvantage of this approach is that the request will always take the specified amount of time regardless the server.

There are many ways to get the length of a string in bash. Using `expr` is a more verbose than other methods but it easier understand than `${#dataToPost}`. The value of dataLen was incremented to include the newline character a few lines later.  This is just to make things look pretty.

The first line of the HTTP request header is the action, POST.

The Host directive is often required. Populate this accordingly from the s_client -connect parameter.

The end of HTTP header section is always denoted by `\r\n\r\n`.

One final note. I may have overused line continuation characters but it is nice to have a single command when manually testing or running inside of a Dockerfile.